# Symfony2/Doctrine2 get joined entities from querybuilder object

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, secondary-indexes

Given two doctrine entities (`Person` and `Company`), associated one-to-many, and a repository which looks something like this

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PersonRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findAllByAge($age) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select('p','c')
                ->leftjoin('p.company', 'c')
                ->where("p.age = :age")
                ->setParameter('age', $age);

        // ...
    }
}
```

How could I retrieve the entity (object or name) of the Company, preferably from the $qb object (or from the Alias, DQL, AST, parser, etc)?

Ideally, I would like to have an array containing all the aliases used by the Querybuilder instance, or at least those defined in the *select* method, together with their entities, in the form:

```
[
    'p' => 'TestBundle\Entity\Person',
    'c' => 'TestBundle\Entity\Company',
    // etc
]
```

In `$qb->getDQLPart('join')` or even something lower level like `$qb->getQuery()->getAST()->fromClause->identificationVariableDeclarations` there's join information regarding the aliases, but it contains only the Root Entity and its alias (p = TestBundle\Entity\Person).

`getRootEntity`, `getRootAliases`, `getAllAliases` do not help as I get the root entity and/or all aliases, but no way to link them together.

`$em->getClassMetadata($rootentity)->associationMappings` gives me associations for the root entity, and it contains target entities for joins, but no aliases. I could map the field names to the information from `$qb->getDQLPart('join')` of course, but that would get me into an area where i'd have to crawl the information *recursively* from each entity object. That seems like it could cause serious errors.

How does the Querybuilder translate the associations to the right entities? Or does it not do that at all, just parsing to the lower level stuff without ever knowing what entities it is using?

I need the info so I can ensure certain entity fields have specific secondary indexes on them. These secondary indexes can be set using annotations, and are stored in the entity by doctrine (`$em->getClassMetadata($entity)->table['indexes']`).

I need to know (programmatically) which fields have secondary indexes while building a query, and would prefer staying as high up the abstraction tree as possible.

Comment: Theoretically it *should* be possible to find entity names of any alias (including the names of joined entities). Doctrine itself is throwing exceptions in the from of `Class Foo has no field or association named bar`, where Foo is some joined entity.

Answer (score 2):

The way you should do this is quite simple:

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PersonRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findAllByAge($age) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->where("p.age = :age")
                ->setParameter('age', $age);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

... then, when walking the response:

```
$people = $personRepository->findAllByAge($age);
$companies = array_map(function ($person) {
    return $person->getCompany();
}, $people);
```

I know what you think: wouldn't that create unnecessary requests? Isn't it possible to get all of that in a single SQL call? Well it is indeed possible but it is not as straightforward as this by a long shot.

I wouldn't recommand it unless there is a huge need in performance for that request (like a massive import/export). But since Doctrine already adds an abstraction layer I supposed performance was not an issue here.

**EDIT:**

Well then in that case the best you could do is to use [native queries with custom result set mappers](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html). Because of the way repositories work, regular DQL queries declared within them will always expect to return the entity of the repository (in your case it will try to spit out a `Person` instance), so I'm afraid there is no real way around it.

It is actually for the better since DQL adds an abstraction layer that is unwelcome in the case of performance-intensive queries.

For long queries I also highly recommand the use of `->iterate()`, which will split the request into smaller chunks. In the end your method should look like this:

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PersonRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllByAgeIterator($age)
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
        // RSM configuration here

        $qb = $this->_em->createNativeQuery("
            // Your SQL query here
        ", $rsm)->setParameter('age', $age);

        return $qb->getQuery()->iterate();
    }
}
```

I did not detail the `ResultSetMappingBuilder` configuration but I think you will find out just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do indeed need to get a smaller subset at the database level, as it involves tables with millions of records, often with complex joining and ordering. So I need to retrieve the secondary index information from doctrine before executing the query.

I need this information to be able to apply an andWhere() to the querybuilder, after which it is further restricted using the doctrine paginator.

Comment: Ah, nice edit. Together with a few hours of reading the Doctrine code on Github, I've come to the conclusion that this approach might not work, or not without grossly abusing Doctrine. The problem is that we have a a bunch of separate Symfony projects, with hundreds of entities. They all share one (privately developed) vendor bundle, which has methods taking a QB as an argument, applying some custom functionality (using classes which extend `FunctionNode`) and returning a QB back. So I can't actually create a native query, just take a querybuilder and return a querybuilder.

Comment: And while it would have been nice to detect the secondary indexes defined in the entity @Index annotation automatically (for safety), I think I'll just have to force the end users to provide an array of fieldnames/aliases when they call the transformation/filter method.

Comment: Do you really have to use that bundle for that specific query? Can't you extend it so using iterators become possible? Also, be aware that you can iterate manually if the built-in functionnality doesn't suit you (just use `->setMaxResults()` and `->setFirstResult()`) ; that would allow you to continue using QB instead of iterators (native queries generate QueryBuilders just like DQL do).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can return collection of `Company` objects directly from query, even from `PersonRepository`:

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PersonRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function findAllByAge($age) {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('YourBundle:Person', 'p')
            ->select('c')
            ->distinct()
            ->leftjoin('p.company', 'c')
            ->where("p.age = :age")
            ->setParameter('age', $age);

        // ...
    }
}
```

I am not sure if returning `Company` instances from `Person` repository is good, but it is mainly convention issue. Of course you can always create `CompanyRepository::findAllCompaniesWithEployeesAtAge($age)` and inverse join like:

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CompanyRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function findAllCompaniesWithEployeesAtAge($age) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c')
            ->distinct()
            ->leftjoin('c.person', 'p') // or whatever inverse side is called
            ->where("p.age = :age")
            ->setParameter('age', $age);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both options require me to execute the query though. I get a querybuilder, determine which of the selected fields have a secondary index, add an andWhere() to the querybuilder using that index, and must return the querybuilder *without* executing it (as it is fed to Doctrine's built-in paginator and hydrated in a specific way). In all cases I only can retrieve the root entity class, not any of the joined entities.

Comment: So I don't get the problem... What do you want to achieve?